# azure storage: how to increase egress limits?

Tags: azure, azure-storage

I want to increase the egress and ingress limits for my storage account but I see this: [image]

my question is:

1. how to increase the egress limits?
2. I confirmed that my storage is of type GPv2 but it is not showing up in the storage account drop down list. So as advised I selected 'None' and proceeded to request for higher ingress bandwidth. So does this mean all storage accounts under the selected {subscription,region} get this newly requested higher ingress bandwidth?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Maximum egress for general-purpose v2 and Blob storage accounts is 50Gbps. You have got the limit and you need to increase this by contacting [Azure Support](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/support/faq/). More details, you can refer to this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/scalability-targets-standard-account?toc=/azure/storage/blobs/toc.json#scale-targets-for-standard-storage-accounts).